# Hibernate code generation: Create abstract/concrete model class pairs

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, code-generation, freemarker

**What is given:**

- I generate my model classes with hibernate code generation (hibernate tools 4)
- I want for each database table an abstract base class, as well as a concrete extension
- The base class should contain all database fields (get/set)
- The concrete class should extend from base and should be empty for transistent fields
- I handle my libararies with Apache Maven
- I have a java configurated Spring MVC environment

I have read that you can override the Freemarker templates in hibernate tools JAR. But as I use Maven this is not possible.?

Because I use a java configurated Spring MVC environment it would be great, if a solution without xml would exist.

The solution should do the following:

- Create a class pair for each table in MySQL database
- I am not shure, but add `@MappedSuperclass` annotation?

**Example:**
Abstract base class

```
@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "employee", catalog = "test", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "E_MAIL"))
public abstract class EmployeeBase implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;

    public Employee() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

**Example:** Concrete class

```
public class Employee extends EmployeeBase {
   // my transistent fields, for example getFirstAndLastName();
}
```

Comment: Using `<dependencyManagement>`, you should be able to point Maven at your custom version of the hibernate tools JAR instead of the one from the repos. (I.e. you'd get the tools JAR, modify the templates, then install it into your local or site repo under your company's `groupName`.)

Comment: Okay thanks, i will check this, but I still have no good approach to write such templates which matches my requirements.

Comment: What's behind this lack of an approach? Have you looked at the existing templates? Have you tried googling for "hibernate custom templates"? Poked at the [Hibernate Tools docs](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.1.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#hbmtemplate) to at least look where to look next? Anything besides listing your high-level requirements here?

Comment: I found this hibernate jira entry https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HBX-1110, which I now try to implement. I just asked, because maybe someone had the same problem and has already a working solution.

Comment: That's not really what SO is for, sorry. The general expectation is that you do what you can on your own before posting.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

1. Create two ReverseEngineeringStrategies (Base and Concrete)
2. Update Freemarker Templates from HibernateTools.jar
3. Create Code Generation Configuration in Eclipse (Hibernate Plugin) and set strategies and custom templates.
4. Switch reverse engineering strategy and run twice.

**Source:**

***BaseClassStrategy:***

```
public class BaseClassStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy {

    public BaseClassStrategy(ReverseEngineeringStrategy delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, MetaAttribute> tableToMetaAttributes(TableIdentifier tableIdentifier) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, MetaAttribute> metaAttributes = super.tableToMetaAttributes(tableIdentifier);
        if (metaAttributes == null) {
            metaAttributes = new HashMap<String, MetaAttribute>();
        }

        // Update modifier
        if (!metaAttributes.containsKey("scope-class")) {
            MetaAttribute metaAttribute = new MetaAttribute("scope-class");
            metaAttribute.addValue("public abstract");
            metaAttributes.put(metaAttribute.getName(), metaAttribute);
        }

        // Update class name
        if (!metaAttributes.containsKey("generated-class")) {
            MetaAttribute metaAttribute = new MetaAttribute("generated-class");
            metaAttribute.addValue(tableToAbstractClassName(tableIdentifier));
            metaAttributes.put(metaAttribute.getName(), metaAttribute);
        }

        return metaAttributes;
    }   

    private String tableToAbstractClassName(TableIdentifier tableIdentifier) {
        String className = super.tableToClassName(tableIdentifier);
        int dotIndex = className.lastIndexOf('.');
        return className.substring(0, dotIndex + 1) + className.substring(dotIndex + 1) + "Base";
    }
}
```

***ConcreteClassStrategy:***

```
public class ConcreteClassStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy {

    public ConcreteClassStrategy(ReverseEngineeringStrategy delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, MetaAttribute> tableToMetaAttributes(TableIdentifier tableIdentifier) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, MetaAttribute>  metaAttributes = super.tableToMetaAttributes(tableIdentifier);
        if (metaAttributes == null) {
            metaAttributes = new HashMap<String, MetaAttribute>();
        }


        String className = super.tableToClassName(tableIdentifier);
        int dotIndex = className.lastIndexOf('.');
        String abstractClassName = className.substring(dotIndex + 1) + "Base";

        // Update extends modifier
        if (!metaAttributes.containsKey("scope-class")) {
            MetaAttribute metaAttribute = new MetaAttribute("extends");
            metaAttribute.addValue(abstractClassName);
            metaAttributes.put(metaAttribute.getName(), metaAttribute);
        }

        return metaAttributes;
    }
}
```

***Hibernate Templates:***

Add following folder structure to your project:

```
src/main/resources
|-> hibernate-templates
    |-> dao
    |-> pojo
```

Copy the pojo AND dao folder from hibernate-tools.jar and update following files. It will only work, if you add both folders!

***Ejb3TypeDeclaration.ftl***

```
<#if ejb3?if_exists>
<#if pojo.isComponent()>
@${pojo.importType("javax.persistence.Embeddable")}
<#else>
@${pojo.importType("javax.persistence.Entity")}
@${pojo.importType("javax.persistence.Table")}(name="${clazz.table.name}"
<#if clazz.table.schema?exists>
    ,schema="${clazz.table.schema}"
</#if><#if clazz.table.catalog?exists>
    ,catalog="${clazz.table.catalog}"
</#if>
<#assign uniqueConstraint=pojo.generateAnnTableUniqueConstraint()>
<#if uniqueConstraint?has_content>
    , uniqueConstraints = ${uniqueConstraint} 
</#if>)
</#if>
</#if>
```

***Ejb3TypeDeclaration.ftl***

```
<#if ejb3?if_exists>
<#if pojo.isComponent()>
@${pojo.importType("javax.persistence.Embeddable")}
<#else>
@${pojo.importType("javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass")}
</#if>
</#if>
```

***Pojo.ftl***

```
${pojo.getPackageDeclaration()}
// Generated ${date} by Hibernate Tools ${version}
<#assign classbody>
<#include "PojoTypeDeclaration.ftl"/> {

<#if !pojo.isInterface()>

<#if pojo.getDeclarationName()?ends_with("Base")>
<#include "PojoFields.ftl"/>
</#if>

<#include "PojoConstructors.ftl"/>

<#if pojo.getDeclarationName()?ends_with("Base")>

<#include "PojoPropertyAccessors.ftl"/>

<#include "PojoToString.ftl"/>

<#include "PojoEqualsHashcode.ftl"/>
</#if>

<#else>
<#include "PojoInterfacePropertyAccessors.ftl"/>

</#if>
<#include "PojoExtraClassCode.ftl"/>

}
</#assign>

${pojo.generateImports()}
${classbody}
```

***PojoConstructor.ftl***

```
<#--  /** default constructor */ -->
public ${pojo.getDeclarationName()}() {}

<#if pojo.needsMinimalConstructor()>    
<#-- /** minimal constructor */ -->
public ${pojo.getDeclarationName()}(${c2j.asParameterList(pojo.getPropertyClosureForMinimalConstructor(), jdk5, pojo)}) {
    <#if pojo.getDeclarationName()?ends_with("Base")>
        <#foreach field in pojo.getPropertiesForMinimalConstructor()>
        this.${field.name} = ${field.name};
        </#foreach>
    <#else>
        super(${c2j.asArgumentList(pojo.getPropertyClosureForMinimalConstructor())});        
    </#if>
}
</#if>    

<#if pojo.needsFullConstructor()>
<#-- /** full constructor */ -->
public ${pojo.getDeclarationName()}(${c2j.asParameterList(pojo.getPropertyClosureForFullConstructor(), jdk5, pojo)}) {
    <#if pojo.getDeclarationName()?ends_with("Base")>
        <#foreach field in pojo.getPropertiesForFullConstructor()> 
        this.${field.name} = ${field.name};
        </#foreach>
    <#else>
        super(${c2j.asArgumentList(pojo.getPropertyClosureForFullConstructor())});        
    </#if>
}
</#if>
```